# What's the difference between Request() and Request.Form()?

Tags: asp.net, http

Been working on a classic asp page. I've been using `Request.Form("x")` and saw that I can also use `Request("x")` to accomplish the same result.

What is the difference between the two? If they're the same I'll just use the later as it saves me some typing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[HttpRequest.Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx) property** will search for the specified key in the [QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx), [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx), [Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies.aspx), or [ServerVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx) collections.

The **[HttpRequest.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) property** will only search among form variables.

**Related resources:**

- [HttpRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Request.Form(x) will check only the posted data whereas Request(x) checks the query string as well.